# Help clarify the limit of $e$ when there is an exponent

Tags: calculus, limits

I want to compute:

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \left(1-\frac{\lambda}{n}\right)^n$$

I know that:

$$e = \lim_{x\to \infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)^x$$

So, I let $x=-\frac{n}{\lambda}$ and get:

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \left(1-\frac{\lambda}{n}\right) = \lim_{n\to \infty} \left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)^{x(-\lambda)} = e^{-\lambda}$$

My question is how do I justify going from $\lim_{n\to \infty} \left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)^{x(-\lambda)}$ to $e^{-\lambda}$?

I thought of the following:
$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)^{x(-\lambda)}=\left[\lim_{n\to \infty} \left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)^x\right]^{-\lambda} = \left[ e \right]^{-\lambda} = e^{-\lambda}$$

I don't think that is right since $-\lambda$ is part of the expression that I want to find the limit for and I don't recall ever learning that we can factor out an exponent from a limit expression.

Please help.

Comment: You answer is correct, buy you can't get it just by letting $=-\frac{n}\lambda$. If $x\to\infty$ then $n\to -\infty$. At least, if $\lambda>0$...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We deal with the interesting case $\lambda$ positive. Note that 
$$1-\frac{\lambda}{n}=\frac{1}{1+\frac{\lambda}{n-\lambda}}$$
(unless $n=\lambda$). Take the $n$-th power of the expression on the right. To make typing easier, study only the $n$-th power of the *denominator*.

Let $x=\frac{n-\lambda}{\lambda}$. Then $n=\lambda+x\lambda$. Thus the $n$-th power of the denominator is 
$$\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)^{\lambda+x\lambda}.$$
This can be written as 
$$\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)^{\lambda}\left(\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)^{x}\right)^\lambda.\tag{1}$$
Now the limit process is uneventful. As $n\to\infty$, $x\to\infty$. Since the function $t^\lambda$ is continuous at $t=e$, the limit of (1) is $e^\lambda$, and therefore our sought-for limit is $e^{-\lambda}$.

Comment: I followed everything until the last sentence "Since the function $e^t$ is continuous ..." could you please show me the algebra too? Also, what were the things you thought of that made you write $1-\frac{\lambda}{n}=\frac{1}{1+\frac{\lambda}{n-\lambda}}$ and $x=\frac{n-\lambda}{\lambda}$? Thank you again for your lucid explanations.

Comment: I did it that way because I have done it before in teaching courses. Don't recall whether I "discovered" the trick myself (as thousands probably have), or saw it somewhere. As to the algebra, $\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)^\lambda=1$ (easy). For the second part, let $f(x)=\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)^x$. Then by continuity of the function $t^\lambda$, $\lim_{x\to\infty} (f(x))^{\lambda}=\left(\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x)\right)^\lambda=e^\lambda$.

Comment: How do I end with $e^-\lambda$? and why did you state that $\lambda$ positive is an interesting case? Thank you again for your time.

Comment: Remember, to make things clearer I have been working with the $n$-th power of the *denominator* in my first displayed formula. To find the limit of the $n$-th power of the original expression, we take the reciprocal. The case $\lambda$ negative, setting $\lambda=-\mu$, leads to looking at the limit of $\left(1+\frac{\mu}{n}\right)^n$. We can just let $x=\frac{n}{\mu}$, so we are looking at the limit of $\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)^{x\mu}$. So the "trick" we used (first displayed formula) is not needed, it is a more routine manipulation. In that case, your method works.

Answer (score 2):

$$\begin{align}\lim_{n\to \infty} \left(1-\frac{\lambda}{n}\right)^n
&=\lim_{n\to \infty} \left(\frac{n}{n-\lambda}\right)^{-n}=\lim_{n\to \infty} \left(1+\frac{\lambda}{n-\lambda}\right)^{-n}=\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty} \left(1+\frac{1}{n/\lambda-1}\right)^{(n/\lambda-1)(-\lambda)-\lambda}=\\
&=\underbrace{\left(\lim_{n\to \infty} \left(1+\frac{1}{n/\lambda-1}\right)^{n/\lambda-1}\right)^{-\lambda}}_{e^{-\lambda}}\cdot \underbrace{\lim_{n\to\infty} \left(1+\frac{1}{n/\lambda-1}\right)^{-\lambda}}_1\end{align}$$